# Changing list into dropdown and adding selected option

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of products.

```
<ul style="padding-left: 0;">
    <li style="text-indent: 0;">
        <a href="/products/category1/sub-category1.html"><span>Category 1</span></a>
        <ul style="padding-left: 0;">
            <li style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category1/sub-category1.html"><span>Sub Category 1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category1/sub-category2.html"><span>Sub Category 2</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="text-indent: 0;">
        <a href="/products/category2.html"><span>Category 2</span></a>
        <ul style="padding-left: 0;">
            <li id="selected_sub_category" style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category2/sub-category1.html"><span>Sub Category 1</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="text-indent: 0;">
        <a href="/products/category3/sub-category1.html"><span>Category 3</span></a>
        <ul style="padding-left: 0;">
            <li style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category3/sub-category1.html"><span>Sub Category 1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category3/sub-category1.html"><span>Sub Category 2</span></a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-indent: 0;">
                <a href="/products/category3/sub-category1.html"><span>Sub Category 3</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="text-indent: 0;">
        <a href="/products/category4.html"><span>Category 4</span></a>
        <ul style="padding-left: 0;">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have some jQuery that can convert the list into a select menu when the screen reaches a certain resolution. Which one to show is controlled by CSS media queries.

```
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("nav");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("nav a").each(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo("nav select");
});
```

This code has the first option as selected always. What I'd like to do is have the option I'm on as being selected. Is there a way to change that easily. I can't seem to figure it out since I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: You have `selected="selected"` for all the options?

Comment: what determines that you have selected an option? and when?

Comment: The ID on the selected option shows which one I've selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the jQuery. It's a simple logic. You are adding `selected="selected"` to all the `<option>` elements:

```
// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",   // Seeee???
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");
```

What you need to do is, remove that line and replace it with some flag or the current URL.

```
// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": (isCurrentLink) ? "selected" : false,
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");
```

You need to define the `isCurrentLink` to return `true` based on the current page selected or the menu item related to the current page.

Comment: The actually shows that selected option is only on the first option which is Go to... That piece of the code is only executed once. It is the second part of the code that deals with all the other options.

Comment: Am I right is assuming isCurrnetLink is a function, rather than a variable?

Comment: @RichardYoung Anything, that can say what's the current link based on the page.

Comment: Okay. I just need to check the currnet page and conpare it with the href attirbute.

Comment: @RichardYoung `location.href == el.attr("href")` - something like that.

Comment: 'selected': location.href == el.attr('href') ? 'selected' : false doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Eh... Let me see what is the best thing you can do.

Comment: location.href should have been location.pathname. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @RichardYoung You are welcome. Glad that got solved and I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.pathname`/variable to compare the `href` property of anchor element, based on it [`.prop(propertyName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) method can be used to set the `selected` property.

```
var el = $(this);
$("<option />", {
   "value": el.attr("href"),
   "text": el.text()
})
.prop('selected', window.location.pathname == el.attr("href"));
```

Comment: Would windoes.location.pathname be the entire URL?

Comment: @RichardYoung No for entire URL use `window.location.href`